# Создать функцию сортировки массива на js

Tags: javascript

Задача состоит в том, чтобы создать функцию, которая сортирует массив

Так не работает:

```
var persons = [
    {name: "Иван", age: 17},
    {name: "Мария", age: 35},
    {name: "Алексей", age: 73},
    {name: "Яков", age: 12},
]
console.log(persons);
function sort(array,fieldName){
array.sort((a,b)=>a.fieldName>b.fieldName?1:-1);
}
sort(persons,"age");
console.log(persons);
```

А так работает

```
persons.sort((a,b)=>a.age>b.age?1:-1);
```

Почему в первом варианте не получается?

Answer (score 3):

Вы сортируете по несуществующему полю

вот так будет работать

```
array.sort((a,b)=>a[fieldName]>b[fieldName]?1:-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

При взятии свойства объекта через точку - `a.fieldName`, ваша переменная игнорируется и пытается получить доступ к свойству `fieldName` у объекта `a`, у которого в свою очередь свойство с таким именем отсутствует. Используйте такой подход `a[fieldName]`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var persons = [
    {name: "Иван", age: 17},
    {name: "Мария", age: 35},
    {name: "Алексей", age: 73},
    {name: "Яков", age: 12},
]

console.log(persons);

function sort(array,fieldName){
  array.sort((a,b)=>a[fieldName] > b[fieldName] ? 1 : -1);
}

sort(persons, "age");

console.log(persons);
```

Подробнее о работе с объектами [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Answer (score 0):

В первом варианте неправильно читается ключ массива, поменяй на вариант с квадратными скобками:

```
array.sort((a,b)=>a[fieldName]>b[fieldName]?1:-1);
```